# check if JsonSerializeObject is null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

How do I check if the <%= JsonConver.Serialize... is null? I tried to wrap it in an if statement, but that didnt seem to work. Right now I get the error that Object reference not set to an instance of an object, which is fine, because on first startup it should be null. Thanks.

```
if( <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email.EmailProgramGroups.ConvertAll<int>(x => x.EmailProgramGroupId))%> !== null){
 var selectedPrograms = <%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email.EmailProgramGroups.ConvertAll<int>(x => x.EmailProgramGroupId))%> ;}
```

Comment: Can you do something like 
`var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionWrapper.....;`
Then check for if output is is null or empty.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean Ani

Comment: Put the if expression in a variable and then check for that variable - if isnullorempty ?

Comment: I gave that a try, but anytime it hits the JsonConvert.serialize.... it throws the error

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
List<int> output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email.EmailProgramGroups.ConvertAll<int>(x => x.EmailProgramGroupId))

if(output.count > 0) {

   //....
}
```